# Reference for triangulated categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, triangulated-categories

As far as I can see, there has been no such request on MO or MSE yet, so let me start one: What are good references for an introduction to *triangulated categories*? Is the canonical reference just Weibel‘s book on homological algebra, would you recommend reading Verdier's original paper or is there some other reference that you like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend Chapter IV of Gelfand-Manin's book on homological algebra as a reasonably thorough and very well-written introduction.

Answer (score 4):

Amnon Neeman has written the research monograph [Triangulated Categories](https://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Neeman/triangulatedcats.pdf). Although it is not intended to be an introduction, you can learn the basics of triangulated categories with the first two chapters. Notice, however, that the monograph contains almost no examples.

As with any chapter in Weibel's book, the chapter on triangulated categories is super-condensed. That can be useful for a quick start, but many details are left to the reader, and many things are left out as well.

Comment: Neeman's book is really not an introduction to triangulated categories at all, but a specialized monograph. In particular, it contains no examples!

Comment: I didn't know that. But "no examples" is not fully correct, see Chapter E. And it *is* an introduction in the sense that the reader does not need to know triangulated categores before reading it. And the first chapters do not look like a specialized monograph, they present the basics of triangulated categories.

Comment: In Appendix E Neeman does *mention* one or two examples by way of exhibiting some quite refined phenomena related to his original results in the book. But he never verifies that any particular category is triangulated, which is certainly one of the most important things for a student first meeting the definition to do, nor does he give a sense of what the full list of important examples is. The book is simply not intended as an introduction.

Comment: @KevinArlin Thank you. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Martin. The link is not working for me. Any chance of fixing it? Thanks.

Comment: A simple google search "neeman triangulated categories" does the job.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the texts already mentioned, the roughly 50-page introductory chapter of the collection of survey articles [*Triangulated Categories*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/triangulated-categories/307C3D943D4CE7F52BAAF7E2BE67F6CC) (edited by Holm T., Jorgensen P. & Rouquier R., published by London Math. Soc.) seems fairly self-contained and starts with additive categories.

Various important examples are covered, such as the homotopy category of complexes on an additive category, the derived category of an abelian category, and the stable category of a Frobenius category.